# presenting a modal view by performing a 3 finger swipe gesture

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitouch

I'm designing a mini drawing app wherein i have to add a feature for launching a color picker modal view by performing a 3-finger swipe gesture. For handling a gesture, a Gesture recognizer is needed but i'm using simple UIResponder methods like touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnded/touchesCancelled methods. 
    When i run 3 fingers across the Drawing view, a color picker modal view needs to be presented. So what i've done is i've loaded a custom modal view controller for launching its specific view as a XIB file when the user removes his/her 3-fingers off the main view. This view is to be presented modally. The modal view code is in touchesEnded: method. 
Here's the code:-

```
  -(void)endTouches:(NSSet *)touches{
//    Remove ending touches from dictionary
NSLog(@"touches- %lu",(unsigned long)touches.count);
for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        NSValue *key= [NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:touch];
        NSLog(@"key- %@,touch- %@",key,touch);
        Line *line= [linesInProcess objectForKey:key];
        NSLog(@"line-%@",line);
        //        If this is a double tap, 'line' will be nil, so make sure not to add it to the array
        if (line) {

            [self.rootObj.completeLines addObject:line];
            NSLog(@"lines made- %@",self.rootObj.completeLines);
            [linesInProcess removeObjectForKey:key];
        }

}
if (touches.count==3) {
    NSLog(@"3 finger swipe");

    ColorPickerController *colorPicker= [[ColorPickerController alloc] init];
    [colorPicker setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
    [colorPicker setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:colorPicker  animated:YES completion:nil];
}
//    Redraw
[self setNeedsDisplay];
 }


 -(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
     [self endTouches:touches];
   }
 -(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
     NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    [self endTouches:touches];
}
```

In the above code snippet, endTouches is just a custom method that can be called either by touchesEnded or touchesCancelled as per the appropriate situation.
      I'm testing this on a device to simulate 3-finger touch. After performing this, when remove the fingers, the touchesEnded: code runs and the control reaches the 'if(touches.count==3)' block. This is when the color-picker modal view (XIB file hooked to ColorPickerController) should be loaded. But to my shock nothing happens after the gesture.. I don't understand why this is happening.. Pls assist anybody.

Comment: Why don't you use a swipe gesture recogniser?

Comment: Yes.. u are right..But the thing is that i'm using the touch methods for drawing stuff on the main view.. I'll be using the UISwipeGestureRecognizer but not in this code..Currently, I just want to test the thing using the touchesEnded: method.. Using the UISwipeGestureRecognizer is actually a second challenge i'll solve later..Right now i need to use touch method only.

Comment: Ah I see. Have you thought of using gesture recognisers for the drawing also? You could use a pan gesture recogniser for the drawing. Then you can add a swipe gesture recogniser for the colour picker. Simplifies everything. You can make it so that the three finger swipe doesn't draw by mistake. etc... You can do an awful lot without having to use touchesBegan etc...

Comment: Why is modal view code in the touch based method not doing anything? When i perform the 3 finger touch, i'm not able to draw anything after that.. This is an important point i had forgotten to mention earlier.. Pls take this into consideration.

Comment: Again you are right.. But removing unintended drawings and scribbling has been taken care of in touchesMoved: method. I just removed the contents of the linesInProgress dictionary.. This way, while performing a 3 finger swipe, i'm not drawing 3 lines. You are absolutely right about using gesture recognizers, but the challenge isn't asking that.. That is a second challenge.. I have to work within the touch methods for right now.

Comment: Whats wrong with the touchesEnded code? The idea is to bring up the modal view as soon as 3 fingers on screen are removed.. That is exactly what i've done.. Pls assist.. I need to solve this thing urgently.. I have already wasted a lot of time on this challenge.

Comment: Is anyone gonna help me out here with this problem. I need to figure this out at the earliest. I'm only allowed to used touch based methods. Gesture based delegate methods are not allowed for what I'm doing.

Comment: It sounds like this is some sort of homework? Really the best way of doing this is with gesture recognisers. I know you said you're not allowed to use them but that says to me that this is either a homework assignment of some sort or you have to speak to the person and ask why they aren't allowed.

Comment: Actually I'm solving a book excercise and the question has two parts..the first part doesn't require u to use gesture recogniser. The second part asks u to do the first part using gesture recognisers.

Comment: And besides the assignment I really want to understand as to why can I not realise the solution using this way if really this isn't the way it is supposed to be solved. I completely am aware that using a swipe gesture recogniser would simplify things. But I want to learn every aspect of the touch and gesture's inner mechanisms. I hope u understand

Comment: Can I please know what i have done wrong in the above code?

Comment: What is touches.count's log output? I think touchesEnded is already called when the first finger is removed (this may be just some millis before second and third finger) but this means touches.count is never 3.

Comment: Yeah, when I remove just any one of the three fingers, touches.count is logged as 1. When I remove the remaining 2 fingers simultaneously a little later, touches.count is logged as 2. But the thing is that each time I've tried to bring up the modal view by running 3 fingers across the view, I make sure to release all the 3 touches simultaneously so that touches.count logs as 3 which should lead to moving of control flow to process the 'if block' from where I launch the modal view.

Comment: The funny things is that after I'm done performing the 3 finger touch and releasing them, from then onwards I'm no longer able to draw stuff on the view. It's like the view froze up for some reason. The XIB file which is to be loaded by the modal controller gets loaded up but it doesn't appear. The viewDidLoad method is logged to the console ( I checked it) but the viewDidAppear doesn't log.

Comment: Hold on a sec, the viewDidAppear is getting logged to the console, but the view in actuality isn't appearing on the screen. By view I mean the modal view that I'm trying to launch with 3 finger touch

Comment: Could this be a problem with the XIB itself or what..